What song about a little eagle is the widow of a Chernobyl clean-up worker referring to?
In Chernobyl Prayer (or Voices from Chernobyl), the widow of a clean-up worker talks to Svetlana Alexievich about the heroism they believed in before the demise of the Soviet Union and says,

At one time, I envied heroes. Those people who had a part in great events, when everything was in the balance, conquering great summits. That was how we talked then, what we sang about. Such splendid songs. (Sings) ‘Little eagle, little eagle …’ I can't even remember the words now. ‘Fly higher than the sun …’ Is that right?

(Chernobyl Prayer, translated by Anna Gunin and Arch Tait. Penguin, 2016. Page 214.)
What is the song the widow is trying to recall?

Googling by "орленок советская песня", this must be Orlyonok (Little Eagle, Eaglet)
https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Орлёнок_(песня)
The first line is

Орлёнок, орлёнок, взлети выше солнца

According to Wikipedia, this was a very famous song in Soviet Union, being popular among partisans in WWII, and popularised further after the war. (Although I must admit that, being born in 1985 in Soviet Union, I've never heard this song before.)
I've found a few translations here:
https://lyricstranslate.com/en/orlyonok-eaglet.html
For example, the translation #1 there starts

An eaglet, An eaglet
Soars up above the sun,

The translations use the word "eaglet" (a young eagle) for "орленок", which is a more precise translation than "little eagle". However, the translation "little eagle" is also possible, especially taking into account that "орленок" has a widely used Russian suffix "онок/енок", which denotes a child of an animal, or a small object in general, and such words are often translated into English using the word "little" (and vice versa).
